# How to calculate time different in start and end date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a two date fields start and end dates. I need to get this two dates date difference to split **days** & **hours** & **minutes** & **seconds** in mongoDB

**Collection Records**

```
[
  {
    "startDate": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1630926969195"
      }
    },
    "endDate": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1648558585308"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I need results of below.

**Results**

```
{
    days: 204,
    hours: 1,
    minutes: 40,
    seconds: 16
}
```

[Play Ground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Y-FTviP21B)

Comment: What specifically is the current problem. Is it that the values aren't what you are expecting (e.g. `days: 204` in the play ground versus "_9 Days_" in your final output note), or are you wanting the information to be reported as a string, or something else?

Comment: 204 days is only correct. but i want exact output in mongodb. I added the Typescript code operation in above last of the code "Typescript sample operation code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this result you will need to use [the arithmetic operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-expression-operators) to calculate the deltas. To calculate `hours` for example:

```
      hours: {
        "$subtract": [
          "$totalHours",
          {
            "$multiply": [
              "$days",
              24
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

While you could do this in a single stage, the nesting may get a little messy. I chose to use a series of `$addFields` stages to do this instead for readability purposes. [Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vZmaJZJ9HWQ), with output from your sample input document being:

```
[
  {
    "days": 204,
    "hours": 1,
    "minutes": 40,
    "seconds": 16
  }
]
```